# Parameter value explanation in log4j.xml

Tags: java, xml, spring, log4j

**log4j.xml**

```
<appender name="console" class="org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender">
    <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
        <param name="ConversionPattern" 
               value="%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %-5p %c{1}:%L - %m%n" />
    </layout>
</appender>
```

From parameter value pattern I can get that `%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss}` stands for some date format specifier, but I want to know about other patterns like what `%-5p`, `%c{1}:%L`, etc stands for?

Comment: You can play with your pattern online: http://log4jtester.com/?p=%25d%7Byyyy-MM-dd+HH%3Amm%3Ass%7D+%25-5p+%25c%7B1%7D%3A%25L+-+%25m%25n

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out [log4j pattern layout](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/apidocs/org/apache/log4j/PatternLayout.html)